# Reusing Code In Commands, i.e. Creating a BaseCommand to reuse "use" statements, arguments, and common variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, extends

I'm writing many import commands in Laravel 5.8 that all take the same argument and import a section of the data. For example, I have an `ImportUsersCommand.php`, `ImportFilesCommand.php`, and `ImportNotesCommand.php` that all take a `location_id` argument (there are a ton more commands, but I'm trying to keep this example simple). The scripts all connect to an external MS SQL Server database specific to that location and then run some code to import the data into a MySQL database.

I've noticed that I'm reusing a lot of the same come, and I'd like to refactor it out to something like a `BaseImportCommand.php`.

#### Example Command - ImportUsersCommand.php (What I Currently Have)

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands\Imports;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

// Models
use App\Models\Location;
use App\Models\Files;
use App\Models\Notes;
use App\Models\User;
// ... and the list continues with many more models!

use DB;
use Hash;
use Schema;
use Carbon\Carbon;
// ... and the list continues with many more!    

class ImportUsers extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'import:users {location_id}';
    protected $description = 'Import users from another data source';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info($this->description);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '4000M');            
        $location = Location::findOrFail($this->argument('location_id'));
        Config::set("database.connections.chirotouch", [
            'driver' => env('SQLSERVER_DB_CONNECTION'),
            'host' => env('SQLSERVER_DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('SQLSERVER_DB_PORT'),
            'database' => 'location_'.$location->id,
            'username' => env('SQLSERVER_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('SQLSERVER_DB_PASSWORD'),
        ]);
        // ... and the code continues just for setting up the command...

        // Only after about 100 lines of code do we actually get to the 
        // specifics of what this particular command does.

        foreach ($location->users as $user) {
            // Do what I need to do
        }
    }
}
```

#### What I'd like ImportUsersCommand.php to look like

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands\Imports;

use App\Console\Commands\Imports\BaseImportCommand;

class ImportUsers extends BaseImportCommand
{
    protected $signature = 'import:users {location_id}';
    protected $description = 'Import users from another data source';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        foreach ($location->users as $user) {
            // Do what I need to do
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm having trouble drafting my `BaseImportCommand.php`. How can I extract the `use` statements, the connecting to the external DB, the `$this-info()` statements, the configuration statments such as increasing the memory limit, and the assignment of the `$location` variable to another file that can be reused for every import command?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit', '4000M');`? Your script shouldn't spend that much of memory...

Comment: @Raptor, I agree it SHOULDN'T use that much memory, but these are scripts that will be running A LOT of data, and even though I'm chunking data, streaming file uploads, and unsetting variables, etc. to conserve memory as I go along, I just don't ever want to run out of memory while doing this... plus, I have the memory to spare.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it.

Your custom command extends your common BaseImportCommand which extends Laravel's Command.

You can set up all of your common use statements in your `BaseImportCommand` file.
And any common code that your commands need for setup can in the `__construct()` inside `BaseImportCommand`, which you already have, but it's just empty.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! One of the problems I've come up against when putting the common code in the `__construct()` section in the `BaseImportCommand` is that the code doesn't seem to have access to the argument `location_id`, and thus can't connect to the remote SQL Server instance. Any suggestions for obtaining arguments from with the `BaseImportCommand`?